# How can I install the Rule Designer on Eclipse for the Business Rules service on Bluemix?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, business-rules

I want to use the Business Rules service on Bluemix (powered by ODM) provided by IBM. 
I have tried to setting up Rule Designer into Eclipse with the [manual](https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/#services/rules/index.html#rulov002). However, I can’t find the URL or Location for Eclipse update site on this manual. Could you tell me the way to setting up the software?

Answer (score 1):

If you see [point **6**](https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/#services/rules/index.html#rulov002)

6. In the Add Repository dialog, enter the following repository details.
      **Name:** Business Rules Service Rule Designer
      **Location:** http://businessrules-updates.eu-gb.bluemix.net/

**Update site location:** http://businessrules-updates.eu-gb.bluemix.net/