# Unable to install the Rule Designer on Eclipse for Business Rules service on Bluemix?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, rule-engine, business-rules

I followed steps given at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882123/how-can-i-install-the-rule-designer-on-eclipse) and [bluemix](https://console.au-syd.bluemix.net/docs/services/rules/index.html#rulov002).

I am facing below issue while installing the Rule Designer plug-in for Eclipse, to work with the Business Rules service on Bluemix:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.
>
> Software being installed: IBM Decision Server Designer Base
>   8.7.0.1-20150313_1905   (com.ibm.rules.studio.base.feature.feature.group
>   8.7.0.1-20150313_1905)   Missing requirement: IBM Decision Server Designer Base 8.7.0.1-20150313_1905
>   (com.ibm.rules.studio.base.feature.feature.group
>   8.7.0.1-20150313_1905) requires 'org.eclipse.draw2d.feature.group [3.8.0,3.9.0)' but it could not be found

Any help!!

Comment: Did my recommendation below help?

Answer (score 0):

@panther, please ensure that the directory where Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 is installed has write permissions. I have seen this error before when Eclipse was installed in the "Program Files" directory in Windows and it did not have write permissions. Try installing Eclipse at root level (e.g. C:) and follow the [steps in the documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/rules/index-gentopic1.html#genTopProcId2) again.

Comment: Even after copying to D drive, error remains the same. I verified the write permission is there at D Drive.

Comment: Make sure you are installing on Eclipse Juno 4.2.2: Go to Help/ Install New Software, select "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"
Search for the word "XSD", and install the component. Once you restart Eclipse, please follow the steps in  the documentation again.

Comment: Can you try doing a fresh install on C (not just copying into it) and follow the steps again?

Comment: @panther, were you successful in installing the Rule Designer yet?

Comment: No, Its still the same. Here is what i did: I configured fresh Eclipse JUNO from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1 at my C drive.
While doing  Help/ Install New Software, select "Juno - download.eclipse.org/releases/juno";; I got below error
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/content.xml.
Unable to locate secure storage module (org.eclipse.equinox.security.windowspasswordprovider).

Comment: Hi, Could you try adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the end of the eclipse.ini file, and use port 80, as suggested in https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/270718/ ?

Comment: Problem is still the same. I tried adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the end of 'eclipse.ini', however couldn't change port 80. I am running eclipse instance at my office network and it is using default 'Automatic detect setting' option.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to chose the right Eclipse version, fitting with the number of bits of your Java version! (I had 64 but it seemed to be 32, with all same errors as mentioned!)